# Guidelines for graphic work for a desktop app

Tags: macos, cocoa

When developing a Mac desktop application (cocoa), do you generally create a working version of the application using default buttons/styles and then apply custom graphics, or is it preferable to start off with graphics done place?

i.e. is it hard to retrofit the application, or are their any issues with either approach?

I have never created a desktop app before (only web), any tips on how apply graphics?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are going to be using custom controls, Then make your graphics first and make sure that the controls support styling. If you are going to be using standard controls then you can make the graphics later because apple does a really great job letting developers customize them.